# A anotação "@required" deve ser importada de que pacote?

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou precisando colocar a anotação `@required` em um construtor:

```dart
class Pacote {
  final int id;
  final int nCodigos;
  final String tabela;

  Pacote({@required this.id, @required this.nCodigos, @required this.tabela});

  // ...
}
```

Só que não tinha nenhuma importação neste arquivo específico. Assim sendo, deu erro de que o `@required` não era um elemento conhecido:

> Undefined name 'required' used as an annotation.
>   Try defining the name or importing it from another library.

O VSCode me sugeriu importar de um dos seguintes lugares:

- `package:flutter/cupetino`
- `package:flutter/widgets`
- `package:flutter/material`
- `package:flutter/foundation`

`cupertino` e `material` são estilos de interface pelo que me lembro, enquanto que `widgets` é referente a elementos visuais. E esse meu trecho de código em específico é apenas uma classe de negócio, sem qualquer conhecimento ou uso em tela.

Então, de onde deveria ser o lugar mais apropriado para se importar e ter acesso à esta anotação, `@required`? É um dos listados ou um outro pacote separado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `@required` é uma anotação utilizada pelo DartAnalyser que é provida através do [meta](https://pub.dev/packages/meta).

Como você não vai utilizar componentes visuais, pode importá-la direto da `foundation`

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
```

De acordo com essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49884464/10145630), foi adicionado essa anotação `@required` direto no SDK através deste package `foundation.dart`

Neste outro link aqui [Required](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/meta/required-constant.html) podemos ver que essa anotação vem do pacote Meta.

O package `foundation.dart` possuí os recursos, classes e funções utilitárias, de nível mais baixo usadas por todas as outras camadas da estrutura Flutter.

Então acredito ser uma boa realmente puxar a referência ao `@required` a partir dela.

*Obs.: Se tua classe for ser usada em um projeto mesclado sem ser necessariamente apenas Flutter, ai sim vale a pena puxar do pacote separado `meta.dart` que é importado no seu pubscpec.yaml*

Answer (score 2):

Realmente muito estranho *Intellisense* sugerir esses `imports`.
Se você deixar o cursor sobre o `@required` verá quando na verdade, o correto seria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

`import 'package:meta/meta.dart';`